# Trying to convert a "chr" column to numeric leads to column full of NAs in R

Tags: r, char, type-conversion, numeric

Thank you in advance for your help!

I need to convert the x.1 column to numeric, to having double float numbers in.

What I have done:
1. I imported the data with: 
`training <- read.csv("training_grover.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")`

2. `str(training)`

Result: `data.frame':   2671 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ X   : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ x.0 : chr  "b" "a" "a" "b" ...
 $ x.1 : chr  "30,83" "58,67" "24,5" "27,83" ...
 $ x.2 : chr  "f" "4.46" "0.5" "1.54" ...
 $ x.3 : chr  "u" "u" "u" "u" ...
 $ x.4 : chr  "g" "g" "g" "g" ...
 $ x.5 : chr  "w" "q" "q" "w" ...
 $ x.6 : chr  "v" "h" "h" "v" ...
 $ x.7 : chr  "1.25" "3.04" "1.5" "3.75" ...
 $ x.8 : chr  "t" "t" "t" "t" ...
 $ x.9 : chr  "t" "t" "f" "t" ...
 $ x.10: chr  "t" "6" "f" "5" ...
 $ x.11: chr  "f" "f" "f" "t" ...
 $ x.12: chr  "g" "g" "g" "g" ...
 $ x.13: chr  "202.0" "43.0" "280.0" "100.0" ...
 $ x.14: chr  "f" "560" "824" "3" ...
 $ x.20: chr  "t" "t" "t" "t" ...
 $ x.17: chr  "116,94256980957068" "225,60625307204938" "92,08407670672422" "104,16291777029285" ...
 $ x.18: chr  "0,5787085579422866" "25,409645364400404" "2,3173371593153314" "8,04533772976642" ...
 $ x.19: chr  "202000.0" "43000.0" "280000.0" "100000.0" ...
 $ x.16: chr  "f" "f" "f" "f" ...
 $ y   : chr  "good" "good" "good" "good" ..`

3. I tried to convert the x.1 column to numeric:

   `training$x.1=as.numeric(training$x.1)`
   As result I got the x.1 full of NAs

Actions:

a. I imported again the file

b. I removed the "," from the x.1:
    `str_replace_all(training$x.1, ",", ".")`

c. Trying again to convert the x.1 column:
    `training$x.1=as.numeric(training$x.1)`
     As result I still get x.1 full of NAs

d. Import again the file

e.  I removed the "," from the x.1:
    `str_replace_all(training$x.1, ",", ".")`

f. Trying again to convert the x.1 column:
    `training$x.1= as.numeric(as.factor(training$x.1))`.
     Result: x.1 column is still full of NAs.

What I am doing wrong here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There might be multiple ways to post-process the data after importing but you can fix the first step by importing the data correctly. Use `dec = ","` to specify character used to represent decimal points.

```
training <- read.csv("training_grover.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

These settings are default in `read.csv2`

```
training <- read.csv2("training_grover.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! I already tried your solution before, with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below for type conversion

```
training$x.1 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",training$x.1))
```

Comment: Thank you, ThomaslsCoding! Your code resolved my problem.Hua!

Comment: Can you explain the usage of the "\\." in the gsub()? Thank you!

Comment: @myhy that is to replace "," to ".", and you need to escape "." by "\\." for regex